# How to access the internet from VPC private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet, vpc

I created on AWS a VPC with a private and a public subnet.
I launched an instance from the private subnet and I would like to access the internet through the NAT server.

This is my iptables on my NAT instance.

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:10234 to:10.0.1.58:22

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    MASQUERADE  all  --  10.0.0.0/16          0.0.0.0/0

What should I add to my NAT or my instance in the private subnet to be able to access the internet from my instance in the private subnet

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `MASQUERADE` rule is good as is. A few other things from the [NAT instance documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html):

1. You should [disable the source/destination check](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck) on the NAT instance to allow it to route traffic
2. Set up the [inbound and outbound security group rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#NATSG) to allow the traffic as needed.
3. Make sure the [route table for your private subnet points to the NAT instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#nat-routing-table)

Comment: I tried that but it seems that it seems that I am missing something in the route table .. I tried to add the NAT instance to my route table but if I try to ping google.com from my instance in the private network I don't get a response (while I get one when I ssh in the NAT instance)

Comment: Actually cleaning up the security groups fixed it ... thanks a lot!

Comment: I had this same problem and, specifically, the solution that worked for me was explicitly adding HTTP and HTTPS to the outbound rules for the NAT security group.

Answer (score 2):

Select the AMI below from Community AMIs and launch the instance in public subnet.
After launching the instance, associate it to private route table in route tables

```
amzn-ami-vpc-nat-pv-2014.03.2.x86_64-ebs (ami-809f4ae8)
```

No need to do anything on the instance, by default it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to achieve this:
[image]

- You can create a custom nat instance in your public subnet
- Add the custom created nat instance as the default gateway inside the routing table that is associated to private subnet

[This](https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/add-a-custom-nat-instance-in-aws-vpc/) step by step tutorial can help you to attach your goal. Hope that will help you

Answer (score 0):

There are two other things you need to do on top of the other answer provided.

You need to and an inbound rule to your nat instance to allow traffic from the private subnet

You also need to disable source/destination check on your nat instance